# NSUserDefaults setObject:forKey: very time expensive

Tags: ios, performance, cocoa-touch, nsuserdefaults

While profiling on the simulator, I noticed that every time I save an `NSNumber` in in `NSUserDefaults` it takes a long time, about 600 ms per instance. Is this normal? I have around 5 of these objects I need to save, so that means in total it takes 3000ms which is a long time.

I am using the following line:

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:object forKey:@"key"];
```

Comment: Show some relevant code.

Comment: how did you come up with 600 ms? I would like to see that logic. On top of it saving 5 is not a straight 600 x 5 multiplication. That almost never happens on computer / device hardware.

Comment: That's terrible performance, are you sure the test is valid?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How much stuff is in your preferences? User preferences is not a database. There's a limit to what you should store there. And I hope you realise that you don't have to synchronise immediately after storing each single item to preferences, so storing five items shouldn't take longer than storing one.

Comment: I do not have many objects in the preferences. What do you mean by synchronise in this case? I save with [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:object forKey:@"key"];

Comment: Turns out you were right, I was saving a huge object I wasn't aware of into my user defaults. Removing it made all the other saves very fast.